# Configure apache rewrite to offer home page at root, when rest of site is at subdir?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, wordpress

For legacy reasons, I have a wordpress site that primarily lives at a subdirectory: http://www.zmxmusic.com/site . However, it also serves the home page at http://www.zmxmusic.com .

I don't have access to the apache config that's currently used, and I'm having difficulty replicating this behavior on a new server.  The wordpress site lives in the filesystem at /srv/zmx/wp/site, and wordpress' home page and siteurl are defined to be http://www.zmxmusic.com/site.  I have this in apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.zmxmusic.com
  ServerAlias ...omitted... 
  DocumentRoot /srv/zmx/wp

  <Directory /srv/zmx/wp>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/zmx_app-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/zmx_app-access.log combined

  RewriteEngine On
  Options +FollowSymlinks

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(site/|index\.php)
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

and I'm still getting Access Denied at the root. Suggestions?

**EDIT**

Nice catch.  And I got it working, changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.*
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Even worked without adding that slash... it seemed to have mainly been the first `RewriteCond`

(edited because I can't answer my own question yet)

Comment: Change your `RewriteRule` to `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]` - but I don't think this is the issue.  Anything useful in Apache's error log?

Comment: If you found the answer, please answer to yourself below, then check your answer as "valid" in a few hours ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.*
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Even worked without adding that slash... it seemed to have mainly been the first `RewriteCond`